# Cocos2d-x run action - clicked button

Tags: cocos2d-x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGfMU.png)
When I click on the button it will perform the action
help me. it did not work
SpriteFrameCache::getInstance()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("run.plist", "run.png");

```
const int numberSprite = 6;

auto gameSprite = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("run1.png");
gameSprite->setPosition(100,200);
gameSprite->setScale(2);
this->addChild(gameSprite);

Vector<SpriteFrame*> animFrames;
animFrames.reserve(numberSprite);

animFrames.pushBack(SpriteFrameCache::getInstance()->getSpriteFrameByName("run1.png"));
animFrames.pushBack(SpriteFrameCache::getInstance()->getSpriteFrameByName("run2.png"));
animFrames.pushBack(SpriteFrameCache::getInstance()->getSpriteFrameByName("run3.png"));
animFrames.pushBack(SpriteFrameCache::getInstance()->getSpriteFrameByName("run4.png"));
animFrames.pushBack(SpriteFrameCache::getInstance()->getSpriteFrameByName("run5.png"));
animFrames.pushBack(SpriteFrameCache::getInstance()->getSpriteFrameByName("run6.png"));

Animation* animation = Animation::createWithSpriteFrames(animFrames, 0.1f);
Animate* animate = Animate::create(animation);
gameSprite->runAction(RepeatForever::create(animate));


auto button = Button::create("play.png");
button->setTitleText("");
button->setScale(0.5);
button->setPosition(visibleSize / 2);
button->addTouchEventListener([&gameSprite](Ref* sender, Widget::TouchEventType type) {
    switch (type)
    {
    case ui::Widget::TouchEventType::BEGAN:
        auto moveBy3 = MoveBy::create(30, Vec2(2000, 0));
gameSprite->runAction(moveBy3);
    case ui::Widget::TouchEventType::ENDED:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
});
this->addChild(button, 10);
```

Comment: Please type-in the code in the question instead of posting screenshot ([Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question))

Comment: Please write a complete question that can be understood (and found in searches) without looking at a picture. While you're at it, you might also enter an image description to give that link a meaningful text.

Comment: what's the problem ??